# How to pluck the oldest child record from a join in BigQuery SQL where ordered by date and limit 1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, shopify

I'm analyzing Shopify Schema Data with BiqQuery in GCP and trying to join the Shopify **Customers** data to the child record that is **Orders** data so that I can find the very first **Order** for each **Customer** created in a certain time, but limit that to 1...like order by created_at asc, limit 1. I'm not really able to figure this out

```
Select

customers.created_at as customer,
customers.orders_count,
orders.created_at,
orders.order_number

FROM `shopxxx.shopify.customers` as customers

Join  `shopxxx.shopify.orders` as orders

on customer = orders.customer

WHERE
 customers.orders_count  != 0 
AND customers.created_at > "2018-09-12 00:00:00 UTC" and  customers.created_at < "2019-09-12 23:59:59 UTC"

and  orders.source_name != 'web' 


order by  customers.created_at desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  customers.customer_id,
  customers.created_at AS customer,
  customers.orders_count,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(orders.created_at AS created_at, orders.order_number AS order_number) ORDER BY orders.created_at LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM `shopxxx.shopify.customers` AS customers
JOIN `shopxxx.shopify.orders` AS orders
ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
WHERE customers.orders_count  != 0 
AND customers.created_at > "2018-09-12 00:00:00 UTC" AND  customers.created_at < "2019-09-12 23:59:59 UTC"
AND  orders.source_name != 'web' 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY customers.created_at DESC
```

or different approach

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  customers.customer_id,
  customers.created_at AS customer,
  customers.orders_count,
  orders.created_at AS created_at, 
  orders.order_number AS order_number
FROM `shopxxx.shopify.customers` AS customers
JOIN (
  SELECT customer_id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(created_at, order_number) ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
  FROM `shopxxx.shopify.orders` 
  WHERE source_name != 'web' GROUP BY customer_id
) AS orders
ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
WHERE customers.orders_count  != 0 
AND customers.created_at > "2018-09-12 00:00:00 UTC" AND  customers.created_at < "2019-09-12 23:59:59 UTC"
ORDER BY customers.created_at DESC
```

Comment: Wow. This just pointed me in a whole direction of learning. I know what I'm doing tonight.

Comment: This is super cool and helpful. It helped me rework a query that kept giving me the error: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlate